# Best approach to store time series data for each product in a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time-series, blob

Lets say we have around 20 GPS devices set up a day. After initialization process each devices will start sending us recieved data hourly.
I need to define a row foreach devices base on name, categories, device id, product number and etc. For every single device I have to store a hourly time series data which might be used for various queries.
So I will have a table of different devices and several time series data linked to it.
Whats the best approach for such a scenario?
Should I define blob columns and store each data and its corresponding timestamp inside it, or should I create a .csv file for each row and then store data inside that file? Both of these methods will limit me in case of a bit complex query generating.
Or is there any suitable method for such cases, am not very familiar with many MySQL features.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should consider using a database optimized for time series, such as InfluxDB or TimescaleDB (PostgreSQL). MySQL might do the job for small datasets, but you may sooner experience performance issues and lack some common time series functionality that InfluxDB and or TimescaleDB have to offer, such as grouping raw data points per time period (hour, day, week).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, I have been looking for a solution to this issue for some time, I got acquainted with PostgresSQL and his capabilities in this issue. However, at the moment it is not possible to switch from MySQL to PostgresSQL , what is the best solution for MySQL ?